# How to explicitly manage multiple pool allocators for heterogeneous types (and sizes)?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, c++11

Scenario:  I have a class G that consists (typically) thousands of objects of type derived from class N.  All these objects have a well-defined life-cycle.  First, an object G is constructed, then N-derived objects are added, then some computation is done with G, which doesn't alter the N-derived objects, then G goes out-of-scope, and with it, the constituent N-derived objects.  The N-derived objects in turn contain pointers or standard containers of pointers to other N-derived objects added to the same G object.  G represents a graph with heterogeneous nodes.

My objectives are:

1. Minimise the cost of allocating each N-derived object.
2. To maximise locality of reference for N-derived objects belonging to the same G object.
3. To minimise the cost of deallocation by deallocating a single block for all N-derived objects.
4. To be able to define multiple independent G objects, with independent life-cycles - potentially managing these independent G objects in concurrent threads without thread-synchronisation.

To me, this seemed to demand multiple pool allocators - that allocate as if using a stack... and only release the pooled allocations when the pool is destroyed.

I looked at boost pool allocators - but didn't find a way to establish multiple independent pools for heterogeneous objects of different sizes.

Next, I defined my own custom allocator - but quickly discovered that, while I could pass it as a template argument to standard containers like std::vector, std::set, std::list et al. - allowing me to specify the type of a pool allocator... I come-unstuck because I can't easily specify that two otherwise independent containers should share the same (non-global) allocator pool.  I recognise that one solution would be to use a static/global and restrict myself to only constructing G objects in one thread.  I also thought about using thread-local-storage to associate a custom allocator with the relevant pool... but considered that ugly.  Neither approach straightforwardly supports the interleaved construction of two independent G objects in the same thread.

Have I overlooked an existing solution to my problem in Boost?

Is there a better idiom than using a static/global or thread local storage to achieve my objectives?

**Update**

I've read Stroustrup's faq - and the boost::container documentation. I was very encouraged, at first, by Boost::container - but was disappointed not to see a concrete example of how to use stateful allocators with these containers.  I've been able to simplify my original question to ask... given a structure:

```
struct DataUnit { map<int,string> m; list<int> l; }
```

How can I ensure that, for each instance of DataUnit, there's a single pool from which the internal constituents of m and l are allocated?  If I pass a custom allocator to map and list, m and l get independent instances of this container.  I initially thought I might be able to use get_allocator() to initialize the allocator with my aerena/pool... but, sadly, allocate() is called before the default constructor of vector<...> has returned.. so I can't do that.

Even more strange, I discovered, having dabbled with boost::container for a while... that the vanilla std containers have a get_allocator()  (on MSVC 2010 and 2012 and g++ 4.6.3) which suggests that the standard libraries in these contexts have similar stateful allocator support to boost::container.

Unfortunately, I still have no viable solution to my original problem (though I can now express it more eloquently.)

**Update 2**

Thanks, pmr, your last comment is something I'd award a "correct answer" - if you'd classed it as an answer.  :)  My problem, having found boost::container, was that I had expected its documentation to be explicit about any new functionality - such as passing allocator objects at construct time... and I hadn't checked the boost::container source code properly.  Boost::container, I'm now convinced, offers a very elegant and intuitive (if badly documented) solution to all my concerns above.  Thanks again!

Comment: Don't touch Boost.Pool. It is unmaintained, has bugs and I've never actually seen it speed up anything. Also related: C++11 has stateful allocators, which should do what you want. I'm wondering: Why try to express a graph structure in such a convoluted way instead of as a graph where your derived objects are values attached to the nodes. Most models of a graph in Boost.Graph have a `clear` member, which doesn't deallocate memory and the graph can be reused after that.

Comment: Ah-ha... while G does represent a graph, and - abstractly - at one level - that's what I'm doing, the OO structure is domain specific and would involve a convoluted explanation.  I would be *very* interested in a pointer to a document about C++11 stateful allocators and their current level of compiler support.

Comment: [Boost.Container has stateful allocator support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/container/Cpp11_conformance.html#container.Cpp11_conformance.alloc_traits_move_traits). [See Stroustrup's FAQ for a good introduction](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#scoped-allocator)

Comment: @pmr: Seconding that opinion on Boost.Pool. The one time I used it I immediately regretted the decision and reverted.

Comment: You are welcome to try my "short_alloc.h": http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/stack_alloc.html .  I'm not positive it will solve your problem.  However it is a very small amount of code, dependent upon nothing else, unencumbered by copyrights, and C++11 conforming.  It is also unmaintained, however there is so little code (116 lines complete) you can maintain it yourself.  It also supports independent containers drawing from the same pool.

Comment: For the update: There is a constructor that accepts a value of the allocator. Use this one.

Comment: @pmr: Many thanks, that solved my dilemma.  Boost containers does exactly what I needed - now I've noticed the extra constructor.  (P.S. While my 'graph' is a graph topographically... it is _very_ special purpose. :)

Answer (score 1):

Warning: completely untested code. And I don't know which "idiom" is it - but the 1.5 pages of code below should solve your problem.

```
class GraphNodeAllocator
{
    struct CMemChunk
    {
        CMemChunk* pNext;
        BYTE* data()
        {
            return static_cast<BYTE*>( static_cast<void*>( this + 1 ) );
        }
    };

    CMemChunk* m_pChunk; // Most recently allocated a.k.a. current chunk
    BYTE* m_pFirstByte;  // First free data byte within the current chunk
    size_t m_freeBytes;  // Count of free bytes within the current chunk

    static const size_t cbChunkAlloc = 0x10000; // 65536 bytes per single allocation
    static const size_t cbChunkPayload = cbChunkAlloc - sizeof( CMemChunk );

    void* Allocate( size_t sz )
    {
        if( sz > cbChunkPayload )
            return NULL;

        if( m_freeBytes >= sz )
        {
            // Current chunk has the space
            m_freeBytes -= sz;
            void* res = m_pFirstByte;
            m_pFirstByte += sz;
            return res;
        }

        // Need a new chunk
        CMemChunk* pChunk = static_cast< CMemChunk* >( malloc( cbChunkAlloc ) );
        if( NULL == pChunk )
            return NULL;
        pChunk->pNext = m_pChunk;
        m_pChunk = pChunk;
        m_pFirstByte = m_pChunk->data();
        m_freeBytes = cbChunkPayload;
        return Allocate( sz );
    }

public:
    inline GraphNodeAllocator(): m_pChunk( NULL ), m_pFirstByte( NULL ), m_freeBytes( 0 ) { }

    inline ~GraphNodeAllocator()
    {
        while( NULL != m_pChunk )
        {
            CMemChunk* pNext;
            pNext = m_pChunk->pNext;
            free( m_pChunk );
            m_pChunk = pNext;
        }
    }

    template<typename E>
    inline E* newNode()
    {
        void* ptr = Allocate( sizeof( E ) );
        if( NULL == ptr ) return NULL;
        return ::new( ptr ) E();
    }
};
```

P.S. The idea is borrowed from Microsoft's CAtlPlex class, which is the number one reason why most Microsoft's template containers (lists, maps, hashmaps) are typically 2 times faster compared to their STL counterparts. I became a much happier person since I quit using std::vector, std::set, std::list et al in favor of the ATL's equivalents.

Comment: I expected a suggestion to move to other containers... I'm reluctant to plumb for ATL, however, as my code needs to be cross-platform... and the primary target is Linux.

Comment: The class I've created for you is not a container, it's barely an allocator. It imposes no limitations on where you'll store those nodes after they're constructed with `GraphNodeAllocator::newNode<E>()`.

Comment: The difficulty was not in implementing the allocator itself... but with integrating it with STL (like) containers such that I am in control of which pool (arena) each STL (like) container uses for storage.  I can't see how to effectively control the state of standard stateful allocators so as to associate a single state with multiple containers.  Sure, I could implement my own containers using an allocator like the one above - but I want to avoid re-inventing the wheel.